# Why I cannot push data into empty array inside the async function, getting error as arrayname.push is not a method

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```
let data = [];
async function getUserData() {

     const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api');
     const data = await response.json();
     const user = data.results[0];

     const newUser = [{
        name: `${user.name.title} ${user.name.first}`,
        money: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000),
      }]

 
    data.push(newUser);
   
}

getUserData();
```

```
script.js:32 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.push is not a function
    at getUserData (script.js:32:10)
```

Comment: If `data` is an object, as evidenced by using `data.results[0]`, then it doesn't have a `.push()` method as it's not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Your data becomes object because of `await response.json()` returns JSON Object, check next line: `const user = data.results[0];` - it does not fails.

I see that you have both `let data` and `const data` - Mixing variables? Use unique names instead:

```
let data = [];

async function getUserData() {
     const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api');
     const userData = await response.json();
     const user = userData.results[0];

 
    data.push([{
        name: `${user.name.title} ${user.name.first}`,
        money: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
    }]);
}

getUserData();
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an object, `data.results` is the array. Your local `data` shadows the outer `data`